# The initialization time of a query

Tags: sql, postgresql, explain

I'm new in query analyzing and would like to understand what this concept actually mean. For instance I ran EXPLAIN ANALYZE for some query and got the following row:

```
->  Sort  (cost=816428.39..827478.32 rows=4419971 width=21) 
       (actual time=10780.477..12520.838 rows=4415703 loops=1)
```

As far as I could google around it, in the `actual time=10780.477..12520.838`  the first number means the time spent for initialization, the second one is about the whole time spent for the part of the query.

What does the initialization mean and why it takes the major part of the execution

Answer (score 1):

*Short*: The short answer to your question is that its possible that the initiation time is time taken to find a good Query Execution Plan + **Waiting for Locks**.

*Elaboration*: As given in the [PG Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-explain.html#AEN80884), the two numbers mentioned within 'actual times' are:

- Start time: The time in millisecond when the Node actually started to evaluate. (Since you haven't given the Entire `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` output, can't tell for sure whether this is the first Node in the execution plan). Now if this is the first Node to be evaluated, then this time is effectively the time taken to generate a good plan / time spent while waiting to get locks (if required) etc. However, if this is 'not' the first Node in the execution plan, this is the first millisecond when the first data-item reached this Node, from the previous Node in the execution plan.
- Stop Time: The time in millisecond when the Node execution actually stopped. Notably, the second number is 'not' the time taken by the Node, but the stop-time.

To elaborate take a look at this EXPLAIN ANALYSE output below:

```
# explain analyse update t set a = 20 where a = 10;
                                            QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Update on t  (cost=0.00..40.00 rows=12 width=6) (actual time=5719.955..5719.955 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on t  (cost=0.00..40.00 rows=12 width=6) (actual time=0.015..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
         Filter: (a = 10)
 Total runtime: 5719.985 ms
(4 rows)
```

Although the Sequence Scan went through very fast, the Actualy UPDATE took time because in another transaction I locked that row for 5+ seconds... and thus the UPDATE row took more than 5000 milliseoncds (5 seconds) to even begin executing.